# Compiling markdown Simplenotes with pandoc.vim and simplenote.vim

Tags: vim, markdown, pandoc

I would like to use [pandoc.vim](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) to compile markdown [Simplenote](http://simplenote.com/)s that I edit in Vim using [simplenote.vim](https://github.com/mrtazz/simplenote.vim). To use `pandoc.vim` I set my Simplenote file type to pandoc with `let g:SimplenoteFiletype = "pandoc"` in my `_vimrc` (I'm on Windows most of the time).

I don't understand Vim well enough to know why this doesn't work. If I use the default `pandoc.vim` executors I get the normal response as though the `pandoc` command completes successfully, but I can't find the output file. I thought at first that this was because my default directory wasn't writable, but I added `cd $HOME` to my `_vimrc` so that `:pwd` yields `C:/Users/richard`.

Is there a way to do this, or should I plan on explicitly saving files locally before I run `pandoc`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `g:SimplenoteFiletype` to `pandoc` doesn't do anything, according to the simplenote source code. (Look at `autoload/simplenote.vim` on project's github) The only filetype that has any effect is `markdown`.

By default, simplenote uses a scratch buffer, which is not necessarily associated with a file. Pandoc internally uses the name of file in its commands. It probably gets confused when it doesn't find a name.

Saving the notes to a file would probably help.

Comment: Thanks! But now that I try this, I can't save with `:w` or `:save` because Simplenote.vim uses `:w` to update Simplenote.com with the current buffer.

Comment: @RichardHerron: Are you sure it doesn't work if you use the form `:w filename.txt`? As far as I can tell from the simplenote source code, it simple adds an autocommand to the buffer write hook. AFAIK that doesn't *replace* the write.

Comment: I can't generate a file with either `:w file.md` or `:w /path/to/file.md`. I'll drop the package writer a line. Thanks for the help!